# Target :first-child or :nth-of-type(1)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to target the first element inside other elements, but somehow it's not working.

I just want to target the first `h2` in the sidebar.

How can I do that?

I have tried with `first-child` and `nth-of-type`, but it's not working.

```css
#sidebar h2:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="right">
    <div class="container-right">
      <div class="freetext">
        <h2>Heading - target me only</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="freetext">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmadcar8/2/) here.

Comment: _“and I just want to target the first h2 in that sidebar. How can I do that?”_ – you can’t; at least not based on _that_ alone. nth-foo etc. are all based on the DOM position of an element _within its parent_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target `first-child` of parent `div` of `h2`.

```
#sidebar > div > div > div:first-child > h2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Or:

```
#sidebar div.freetext:first-child > h2 {
    color: blue;
}

<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="container-right">
            <div class="freetext">
                <h2>heading - target me</h2>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="freetext">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dmadcar8/5/)

Answer (score 2):

this will do the job.

```css
#sidebar .freetext:first-child h2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="container-right">
            <div class="freetext">
                <h2>Heading - target me only</h2>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="freetext">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```